# Connect Teams with Projects in DependencyTrack

Tags: owasp-dependency-track

We are using DependencyTrack for a bunch of projects in different teams. This is getting more and more confusing.

Is there a way to configure each project to show it only to a specific team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ACL feature for this. In Dependency Track 4.9.0 it is in beta phase and you have to allow it manually.

Go to **Administration** -> **Access Management** -> **Portfolio Access Control** -> **Enable portfolio access control (beta)**

There you can assign specific projects to specific teams. Don't forget to give the team at least `VIEV_PORTFOLIO` permissions.